# Animation in an imageview how to change the series of images dynamically

Tags: android

I want to make an app that have an imageview that will display a series of images as an Animation like 10 images back to back with only few mile seconds separate them and i want to be able to change the series by clicking a button and every time i click it the series of images will change (array of drawables) how can i do that ?

I have tried doing it by making the images a sprite sheet and animate it by calling a drawing method in a run method(thread) but i couldn't change the sprite ..

in addition to that i can't waste much time converting the images into a sprite

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, unfortunately your question does not demonstrate any attempt of prior research. In order to get a good response, it is advised you should show evidence you have attempted to solve the problem, either in code or otherwise, before asking a question.

Comment: okay ed sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the standard AnimationDrawable?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

**UPDATE**

If I have understood what you mean to change the animation played by the imageview you just need to update it in your onClickListener setting the new background, using this code.

```
img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spin_animation);

 // Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
 AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();

 // Start the animation (looped playback by default).
 frameAnimation.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that you need you ViewFlipper and not imageView,
 try like this.

1.in your layout:

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:flipInterval="40"    
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
 >
```

2.and then in your activity:

```
 int gallerySplashrImages[]={/*id of the image you want to display(ex:R.drawable.calque0,R.drawable.calque1,...)*/};

     viewFlipper =(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper); 
     viewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
     for(int i=0;i<gallerySplashrImages.length;i++)
        {
            setFlipperImage(gallerySplashrImages[i]);
        }
```

3.setFlipperImage

```
 private void setFlipperImage(int res) 
  {
ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
image.setBackgroundResource(res);
viewFlipper.addView(image);
}
```